# HTML link preload for async script files benefits

Tags: javascript, html

Facebook released a new mobile version of the web app and I noticed that they are using an interesting pattern to load scripts e.g.:

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yF/r/l7eLlKEkIZ3.js?_nc_x=Sgci3KMqefe" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yF/r/l7eLlKEkIZ3.js?_nc_x=Sgci3KMqefe" data-bootloader-hash="cbBL0" async="1" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="(window._btldr||(window._btldr={}))[&quot;cbBL0&quot;]=1;window.CavalryLogger&amp;&amp;CavalryLogger.done_js([&quot;cbBL0&quot;])" onerror="(window._btldr||(window._btldr={}))[&quot;cbBL0&quot;]=1;window.CavalryLogger&amp;&amp;CavalryLogger.done_js([&quot;cbBL0&quot;])"></script>
```

I'm just curious what are the benefits of this pattern - preloading javascript file and immediately async loading it?